# Test Impact Analysis using TeamCity instead of TeamBuild?

Tags: tfs, teamcity

We currently use Team Foundation Server Team Build for CI/builds but are looking at using TeamCity instead.  Our testing team though is interested in using the Test Impact Analysis that Team Build can provide.

Has anybody had success in getting Test Impact Analysis results out of TeamCity?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the answer you are looking for, since I've never tried to do exactly what you are asking, but I have integrated other 3rd-party analysis outputs before.

What is really great about teamcity is that you can display anything that you can output to HTML as it's own report tab.  So assuming you can get an XML+XSLT or an HTML report of the results you can display it.

Here is the documentation
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results

If the report output is in XML then you will probably need to create an XSLT and convert it as part of your build scripts to get an HTML format you are happy with.

There are a few other ways to extend TeamCity but html reports are definitely one of the easiest:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Extending+TeamCity

Comment: Thanks for this and while handy, it doesn't help with my specific problem.  What I need to do is find out how to run Test Impact Analysis from Team City. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to run it outside of Team Build.

Comment: If it is part of TFS, my guess is that there is no (at least no easy) way to run it under teamcity.  TFS is pretty much a closed box and doesn't play nice with much else.